# Override abstract in a function

Tags: java

I want to add an extra parameter to send()

In DumpSequence.java:

```
private static Receiver sm_receiver = new DumpReceiver(System.out, true);

sm_receiver.send(message, lTicks); (Work)
sm_receiver.send(message, lTicks, addParam1); (Won't work)
```

DumnpReceiver.java I tried to add extra param which is lTimeStamp2:

```
public void send(MidiMessage message, long lTimeStamp, long lTimeStamp2) {...}
```

Error:

```
DumpSequence.java:136: send(javax.sound.midi.MidiMessage,long) in javax.sound.mi
di.Receiver cannot be applied to (javax.sound.midi.MidiMessage,long,long)
                sm_receiver.send(message, lTicks, lTicks);
                           ^
.\DumpReceiver.java:21: DumpReceiver is not abstract and does not override abstr
act method send(javax.sound.midi.MidiMessage,long) in javax.sound.midi.Receiver
public class DumpReceiver
       ^
2 errors
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the @Override annotation from line 21

Answer (score 0):

If you extend an abstract class it needs to define all the abstract method or it needs to be abstract class.

Or if you are overloading method then just remove `@Override` annotation

**See Also**

- [Method Overriding](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.8.1)

Comment: AFAIK, he's not asking that. He wants to add a parameter to the `send` method and call it from `sm_receiver`, a `Receiver` variable

Comment: @Serabe I got to it bit later..already included it in the answer

Comment: Oh, I'm not using any @Override annotation.

Comment: then consider first part as answer :)

Comment: I decided to use Global variable method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `send(MidiMessage message, long lTimeStamp, long lTimeStamp2)` you need to use a `DumpReceiver` instance, not a `Receiver` one. There is no such method in `Receiver

```
private static DumpReceiver sm_receiver = new DumpReceiver(System.out, true);
```

**EDIT:** by inheritance, you can still use it as a plain `Receiver` object.

Comment: Still the same error, I believe that is an interface, not abstract. Is there a way to pass a value in DumpSequence.java to DumpReciever.java? I know Java do not have the ability to read global variable.

Comment: Are you modifying the right variable? Furthermore, if you find yourself doing so, it is usually a Bad Idea (TM). There is probably a workaround you can use so this is not necessary.

Comment: Yes, modifying the right variable. I have limited knowledge on Java, there a way to use 2-steps method but is not really efficient to me.

Answer (score 0):

You still have to implement `send(javax.sound.midi.MidiMessage,long)`, even if you don't use it - it's required by the interface you implemented

Comment: Is there a way to pass a value in DumpSequence.java to DumpReciever.java? I know Java do not have the ability to read global variable.